# Element-less component with bound events

Tags: reactjs

Is there a `React`y way to create a wrapper component of another element that has bound DOM events, without producing another element (as in `<div>`)?

E.g.

```
class TripleClickWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={::this._onClick}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }

  _onClick() { /* counts clicks and handles timeouts etc */ }
}

// somewhere else:

<TripleClickWrapper onTripleClick={::this._doSomething}>
  <SomeComponent />
</TripleClickWrapper>
```

I don't want the extra `<div>` `TripleClickWrapper` creates, but I want to bind `onClick` to the wrapper, without passing it down to `<SomeComponent>`. Any nice way without getting to `DOM`y (`findDOMNode`+`addEventLisetener`+remove on unmout)?

If I didn't need to bind DOM events, I could just return `React.Children.only(this.props.children)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this approach:

- I didn't want an extra `<div>`
- I didn't want my wrapper to override the child's events (so if my wrapped `div` already had `onClick` it should still run
- I didn't want to use `addEventListener` manually on the `findDOMNode(this)`. Reasons: 1) inner `onClick`s can't run `e.stopPropagation()` and stop my added event, as React events run on the `document`, without `useCapture`, and 2) lose React event system goodies.

Currently I'm taking the only child in the wrapper and use cloneElement, as @Calvin Belden recommended, and pass in my events combined with existing events.

```
render() {
  const onlyChild = React.Children.only(children)

  const events = {
    onClick: this.doSomething,
    onMouseEnter: this.doSomethingElse,
    // ...
  }

  for (let [eventName, fn] of Object.entries(events)) {
    if (onlyChild.props[eventName]) {
      let oldFn = onlyChild.props[eventName]
      events[eventName] = e => {
        oldFn(e)
        if (!e.isPropagationStopped()) fn(e)
      }
    }
  }

  return React.cloneElement(onlyChild, events)
}
```

It still forces me to pass in events when I use a component instead of a div: `<TripleClickWrapper><SomeComponent></TripleClickWrapper>`. `SomeComponent` would have to pass down onClick to its div.

Not optimal, but as clean as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an augmented/cloned version of the child component in your render function: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement

You can add additional props during the cloning process.

```
render() {
    const newProps = /* any props/event handlers you want to add */;
    return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), newProps);
}
```

Comment: If I use `cloneElement` I still need to pass the `onClick` to the `<div>` in `<SomeComponent>` (i.e. `<div onClick={this.props.onClick}>`) which I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you wrap simple dom elements, like div, Calvin's answer will work. This is how we implemented tooltip component in Wix's website editor. For wrapping other react component, you have no choice but to use DOM methods like you wrote in your question, or have the wrapped component support event listeners in its props

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code (specifically, this line: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.0.0-rc.2/src/renderers/dom/shared/ReactDOMComponent.js#L621 ) I see that a possible solution might be to inject an EventPlugin. This is because `enqueuePutListener` is called, which in turn calls `ReactBrowserEventEmitter.listenTo` -->  `ReactEventListener.trapBubbledEvent` --> `EventListener.listen` which does the actual `addEventListener`. The `if` statement there looks for a plugin name. I'm not sure how that mechanism works, and didn't find it in the docs, but with some investigation sounds like a possible solution. For example, there's a plugin that handled tap events when 300ms delay was still a thing.

Comment: Interesting. Here's a way to inject a plugin: https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin